# ¿Como puedo simplificar esta estructura de "carrito de compras" básico?

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría simplificar justo esta estructura de "carrito de compras sencillo" ¿como lo puedo hacer?
Cada botón llama a una función, esta va sumando un valor cada vez que el usuario da click y el ultimo botón (sumacompleta) realiza la suma de todo. ¿como lo podría simplificar en una función o como podría hacerlo mas sencillo?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a id='c1' href="javascript:suma1();">Playera</a>
<a id='c2' href="javascript:suma2();">Camisa</a>
<a id='c3' href="javascript:suma3();">Pantalon</a>
<a id='c4' href="javascript:suma4();">zapatos</a>
<a id='c4' href="javascript:sumacompleta();">Total</a>
<p id="suma1"></p>
<p id="suma2"></p>
<p id="suma3"></p>
<p id="suma4"></p>
<p id="suma"></p>
<p id="playeras">$100</p>
<script>
var cuenta1 = 0;
var cuenta2 = 0;
var cuenta3 = 0;
var cuenta4 = 0;
function suma1() {
  cuenta1++;
  var uno = document.getElementById("suma1").innerHTML = cuenta1 + " Playeras";
}
function suma2() {
  cuenta2++;
  var dos = document.getElementById("suma2").innerHTML = cuenta2 + " Camisa";
}
function suma3() {
  cuenta3++;
  var tres = document.getElementById("suma3").innerHTML = cuenta3 + " Pantalon";
}
function suma4() {
  cuenta4++;
  var cuatro = document.getElementById("suma4").innerHTML = cuenta4 + " Zapatos";
}
function sumacompleta() {
  var total = cuenta1 + cuenta2 + cuenta3 + cuenta4;
  document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML = total;
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo como funciona tu codigo, si puedes explicarlo mejor porfavor para entrar en contexto.

Ahora bien veo que tienes la misma estructura de funcion para todas las demas, lo que yo haria es crear una sola funcion y pasarle con 2 argumentos (suma y texto)

```
function sumaGlobal(nsuma,texto){
.......
}
```

esto obviamente es para simplificar codigo pero para el tema de la funcionalidad tendrias que explicar tu codigo bien.

Comment: No se porque aquí no funciona al dar "Ejecutar" (aquí en stackoverflow), pero si pruebas el código, hace lo siguiente: Cada botón llama a una función, esta va sumando un valor cada vez que el usuario da click (por ejemplo a playeras) y el ultimo botón Total (sumacompleta) realiza la suma de todo.